# seed_fu from existing database

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, seed

I wonder if there's a way to auto generate seed_fu files from existing data ?

I'm using Rails 3 and MySql.

seed_fu plugin: https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Top answer no longer works:

```
SeedFu::Writer.write('path/to/file.rb',{ class_name: 'Person', constraints: [:first_name, :last_name]}) do |writer|
  Person.all.each do |person|
    writer << person.as_json
  end
end
```

seed-fu writer uses <<(seed) method to introduce the seed data to the block, top answer will cause a missing block exception.

also you need to pass the class name and constraints inside {options} keys so the writer takes em as options parameters

EDIT

Updated the answer according to [Rails Seed-Fu Writer why seed got commented out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230462/rails-seed-fu-writer-why-seed-got-commented-out) @Albert Netymk comment.

Comment: The above snippet would cause commented output. See this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230462/rails-seed-fu-writer-why-seed-got-commented-out) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
Person.all.each do |person|
```

instead of:

```
Person.each do |person|
```

Comment: More a comment on the accepted answer than a separate answer, but important.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SeedFu::Writer` to generate seed_fu files, see http://rubydoc.info/github/mbleigh/seed-fu/master/SeedFu/Writer for an example.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect current seed_fu version, as recommended [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)