# Rails Seed-Fu Writer why seed got commented out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake, seeding

So, here's my custom rake task:

```
task :backup => :environment do |t|
  SeedFu::Writer.write('/path/to/file.rb', class_name: 'Category', constraints: [:id] do |w|
    Category.all.each do |x|
      w << x
    end  
  end
end
```

And the following result file contains:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE, it was auto-generated.
#
# Date: 2014-06-15 21:08:13 +0700
# Seeding Category
# Written with the command:
#
#   /home/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/rake backup
#
Category.seed(:id,
  #<Category id: 1, name: "foo">,
  #<Category id: 2, name: "bar">,
  #<Category id: 3, name: "baz">
)
# End auto-generated file.
```

**Question: Why did the seedfile got commented out?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, this is a basic string manipulation.**

When I read closely on their source code, `seed` method accepts `Hash`, not object.
So, I simply translated the object to its Hash equivalent:

```
task :backup => :environment do |t|
  SeedFu::Writer.write('/path/to/file.rb', class_name: 'Category', constraints: [:id] do |w|
    Category.all.each do |x|
      w << x.as_json
    end  
  end
end
```

Note that you can use `.attributes` or `.as_json`, but I read somewhere that `.attributes` actually takes a lot more time than `.as_json`.

After that, I encountered yet another problem: `Datetime` columns. When converted to JSON, **Datetime columns are not quoted**. So what I did was:

1. Store the column names (of type `Datetime`) to an array.
2. Store current object's `Hash` to a local variable.
3. Convert the `Datetime` values to `String`, using `.to_s` (in the local variable)
4. Output the modified local variable to `writer` object.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing exact the same problems, commented output and datetime columns are not quoted. It seems that `ActiveSupport::JSON` could kill two birds with one stone.

```
require 'seed-fu'
j = ActiveSupport::JSON
SeedFu::Writer.write("#{Rails.root}/db/dump_seeds/lectures.rb",{ class_name: 'Lecture', constraints: [:id, :name]}) do |writer|
  Lecture.all.order('id').each do |e|
    writer << j.decode(j.encode(e))
  end
end
```

Comment: Outstanding solution, thanks! Seems like a fairly common issue, surprised this Q&A not upvoted more!